# Why does the assignment operator return a value and not a reference?

Tags: javascript

I saw the example below explained on this [site](http://joseanpg.net/jslab/quiz/soshnikov/answers.html) and thought both answers would be 20 and not the 10 that is returned. He wrote that both the comma and assignment returns a value, not a reference. I don't quite understand what that means.

I understand it in relation to passing variables into functions or methods i.e primitive types are passed in by value and objects by reference but I'm not sure how it applies in this case.

I also understand about context and the value of 'this' (after help from stackoverflow) but I thought in both cases I would still be invoking it as a method, foo.bar() which would mean foo is the context but it seems both result in a function call bar().

Why is that and what does it all mean?

```
var x = 10;
var foo = {
  x: 20,
  bar: function () {return this.x;}
};

(foo.bar = foo.bar)();//returns 10
(foo.bar, foo.bar)();//returns 10
```

Comment: `(foo.bar = foo.bar)()` is **so** going on my list of interview questions! ^.^

Comment: @Ben: Not `(foo.bar, foo.bar)()`? ;-) I mean, if you want esoteric...

Comment: @Ben - Let me know who you work for so I don't make the mistake of coming for an interview:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with values vs. references, it has to do with `this` values (as you suspected). In JavaScript, `this` is set *entirely* by how a function is called, not where it's defined. You set the `this` value in one of three ways:

1. Call the function via an object property using property accessor notation, either dotted notation (`obj.foo()`) or bracketed notation (`obj["foo"]()`).
2. Call the function via an object property using a `with` statement (really just a variant of #1, but worth calling out separately, particularly as it's not obvious from the source code)
3. Use the `apply` or `call` features of the function instance.

In your examples above, you're not doing any of those, so you end up calling the function with the default `this` value, the global object, and so `x` comes from there rather than from your `foo` object. Here's another way to think about what that code is doing:

```
var f = foo.bar; // Not calling it, getting a reference to it
f();             // Calls the function with `this` referencing the global object
```

If you don't directly use a property to actually make the call (instead retrieving the *value* of the property and then making the call with that), the `this` handling doesn't kick in.

Comment: It has to do with the Reference Type, since both, the comma operator and the simple assignment internally use `GetValue`, and this causes that the *base object* of the reference to be lost.

Comment: @CMS: Right, that's the underlying mechanism behind the behavior I described. I didn't think delving into those depths was needed. (I didn't talk about the [[Call]] method or [[Scope]] property, either :-) ).

Comment: @TJ & CMS - Feel free to respond as technically as you like. If I don't understand it I will ask you questions. 
Also CMS's response makes more sense to me as I still can't understand why (foo.bar = foo.bar)() doesn't equate to foo.bar(). 
In your example you only used f = foo.bar and that makes sense to me as f() is a function call but if it was f.bar = foo.bar then to me that equates as f.bar() which means f would be 'this'

Comment: @TJ -I forgot to say thanks for taking the time respond to me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Nick, I tried to elaborate more about the behavior of the simple assignment operator, give a look to my edit, and feel free to ask any doubts...

Comment: @Nick: The key to `(foo.bar = foo.bar)()` is to remember that you're calling the *result of the expression*. What's the result of that expression? Right, a function reference -- completely unbound from any property, exactly like `(f = foo.bar)()`. You don't have to delve into the plumbing to understand it, that's the key part. If you *want* to, though, CMS has started you off -- but there's nothing like reading the spec (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm, §8.7). It's heavy going, though; unless you really study it, you may end up more confused, not less. :-)

Comment: @Nick: Continuing, maybe thinking about `(f = foo.bar = foo.bar)()` might help. What's the thing travelling through that series of assignments? The point is that once you've dereferenced `foo.bar` *without* calling it, you just have a function reference, disconnected from the property. The only time it remains connected to the property is if you refer to the property and make the call without an intermediate expression (like an assignment). And kudos, BTW, for hanging out on the fringes of the esoterica of the language. ;-)

Comment: @TJ - I know what's confusing me and it's the dot notation in between the first foo & bar. I'm having trouble understanding how foo.bar can equal just bar() when bar it is a property of foo. That said, your example (f = foo.bar = foo.bar)() helped me a lot and I'll use this until I completely understand what's happening. So, as another ridiculous example would (nick.foo.low.man = foo.man.tan.bar)() still equal bar()?

Comment: @Nick: Yup, because the call isn't made directly through dotted notation. The value is retrieved from the property, assigned to another property and then used (not via either of those properties) when making the call. Have fun!

Answer (score 8):

You should understand how the internal [Reference Type](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.7) works.

<sub>**Note:** This is not a language data type, is an internal mechanism to handle references.</sub>

A reference is composed of two elements, the *base object* and a *property name*.

In your example, the `foo.bar` reference looks like this.

```
// pseudo-code
foo.bar = {
  baseObject: foo,
  propertyName: 'bar'
}
```

Both, the [comma operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.14) and a [simple assignment](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.13.1), rely on getting the value of the property name, that causes the base object to be lost, since a single value is returned (this is made through the internal [`GetValue`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.7.1) operation).

This is how the internal `GetValue` operation works:

```
// pseudo-code
GetValue(V) :
  if (Type(V) != Reference) return V;

  baseObject = GetBase(V); // in your example foo
  if (baseObject === null) throw ReferenceError;

  return baseObject.[[Get]](GetPropertyName(V)); 
  // equivalent to baseObject[v.PropertyName];
```

As you see, a *value* is returned, so the original reference is lost.

**Edit:** The key to understand why `(foo.bar = foo.bar)();` is not equivalent to `foo.bar();` relies in the [Simple Assignment](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.13.1) Operator, let's see the algorithm:

```
11.13.1 Simple Assignment (`=`)
The production `AssignmentExpression` :
               `LeftHandSideExpression` = `AssignmentExpression`

is evaluated as follows:

1. Evaluate LeftHandSideExpression.

2. Evaluate AssignmentExpression.

3.Call GetValue(Result(2)).

4.Call PutValue(Result(1), Result(3)).

5.Return Result(3).
```

Basically when you make `(foo.bar = foo.bar)` the actual assignment (**Step 4.**) has no effect because  `PutValue` will only get the value of the reference and will place it back, with the same base object.

The key is that the assignment operator returns (**Step 5**) the value obtained in the **Step 3** and as I said before in the `GetValue` pseudo-code, this internal method returns a *value* which doesn't really have a *base object*.

Comment: That'll teach me. I said to T.J. Crowder make it as technical as you like but now I can't understand it. I will need to think about what you've written and come back to you if that's OK.

Comment: @Nick, sure, think about it, we are dealing with a completely abstract type, that exist in the specification purely for *expository purposes*. That can make it a little bit tough to gasp. Read about it and about the `GetBase`, `GetPropertyName` and `GetValue` internal methods, then we can go one step further and I can explain you how the Reference type is used to set the `this` value when you make a function call.

Comment: Thanks man. Your understanding of JavaScript is incredible. I will take away what you've said and try to understand it, with some research as well. At this point I have to award the correct answer which I will give to TJ, not because his answer was better as all the responses were great but because I have to choose one. I'll +1 you and the others as I thought they we're all good, helpful answers. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Nick - You're welcome, try to understand it and if you encounter any questions on the way, don't hesitate to ask! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding it.

Both examples are returning the `window`'s `x` property, since they aren't being directly invoked on `foo`.

The value of the `this` keyword inside a function depends on the context in which the function was called.

In an ordinary function call (eg, `myFunc()`), `this` will be the global object, which is usually `window`.
In an object method call (eg, `foo.bar()`), `this` will be the object on which the function was invoked.  (in this case, `foo`)

You can set the context explicitly by calling `myFunc.call(context, arg1, arg2)` or `myFunc.apply(context, argArray)`.

Both of your examples are normal invocations of an expression that evaluates to `foo.bar`.
Therefore, `this` is the `window`.

They are equivalent to

```
var func = (some expression);
func();
```

Comment: I understand everything you've written including your example but in my head (foo.bar = foo.bar) still equates to foo.bar() and not bar() as your telling me (which I know is correct). Both you, CMS and TJ have given me good responses but I need to get my head around it as I'm a bit simple.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to think of the dot operator as behaving similarly to a `with` statement.  When you run `foo.bar()`, the result is much the same as if you ran:

```
with (foo) {
    bar(); // returns 20
}
```

This will run your `bar` function with `foo` overlaid on top of the global object, allowing it to find the `x` in `foo` and thus return 20.

If you don't call `bar` immediately, though, as in `(foo.bar = foo.bar)`, you instead get:

```
with (foo) {
    bar; // returns "bar" itself
}
```

The result is then passed out of the parentheses, producing an intermediate statement like `<reference to bar>()`, which has no dot operator, so no `with` statement, so no access to `foo`, just to the global value of `x`.

(The dot operator doesn't *actually* convert to a `with` statement, of course, but the behavior is similar.)

Comment: Thanks man - That helps me a lot. Hadn't actually used the with statement before but it give me something to research. So in this example (nick.foo.low.man = foo.man.tan.bar)() it would be the same as
with (foo.man.tan) {
    bar; // returns "bar" itself
}