# Brackets in variable initialization

Tags: javascript

I've made an experiment in JavaScript:

```
var x=[  "1","2","3","4","5","6"];

c=(b = x)[2] ;   //<--- what is this syntax?

alert(b ); // 1,2,3,4,5,6

alert(c ); // 3
```

I figured it out how it works. It saves me a line of equalization. Still, I was wondering about this strange syntax. How is it called and where can I read about it?

Comment: see my answer for how `c=(b = x)[2]` works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` operator returns a value being assigned so `(b = x)` returns value of `x`. That results in `x[2]` being assigned to `c`.

(note: "returns `x`" changed to "returns value of `x`" according to comments)

Comment: I believe it should be **That results in `b[2]` being assigned to `c`.**

Comment: @FahimParkar: Actually neither, strictly speaking. The expression `(b = x)` returns neither `b` nor `x`, but the value of `x`. The value originates from the `x` variable, but neither the `b` nor the `x` variable is used to access the array.

Comment: @Guffa : **NO**, it assign as b. See what you get if you have `c=(b=x[1])[2];`. It assign `c=undefined`, its because `c=b[2]` and **NOT** `c=x[2]`. Let me know if you want more explanation...

Comment: @FahimParkar [Simple assignment](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.13.1) returns the value of the right hand side expression, which in the OP's case would be the value of `x` and in your example the value of `x[1]` (not the value of `x` like you suggested). The value of `b` is never really involved.

Comment: @Felix Loether : so what will `c` have in my case (`c=(b=x[1])[2];`)?? will it have `3` or `undefined`?? As per your case, its `3` BUT I am getting result as `undefined`. **See my answer for flow and this is what is happening...**

Comment: @FahimParkar: Isn't the reason that `c` is `undefined` the fact that  "2"[2] is undefined? Btw. if you look at ECMA262, section 11.13.1, it is said there that rvalue is returned and rvalue is a result of evaluating right hand side of `=`.

Comment: @clime : you are getting confused... that is true.. but here for c, it will not check right hand side... see my answer for flow...

Comment: @FahimParkar: You are mistaken. The reason that `(b=x[1])[2]` returns `undefined` is *not* because it returns `b[2]`, but because it returns `x[1][2]`, and because `x[1]` is not an array the result is `undefined`. You can verify that it's the value that is returned by assigning to a read-only variable. The `undefined` variable is read-only in recent browsers, but `(undefined=[1,2])[1]` returns `2`, because the assignment returns `[1,2]`, not `undefined`.

Comment: @Guffa : **because x[1] is not an array the result is undefined** is something WORST... what if i have `c=(b=x[1])[0];`??? will it still display **undefined???** WELL ANSWER is **NO**, it will display `2`.

Comment: @FahimParkar: That depends on the browser. The result of the assignment expression is the string `"2"`, and some browsers allow you to access strings as arrays, so `"2"[0]` returns the first character of the string. If you put the value `"2345"` in the second item in the array, `(b=x[1])[0]` still returns `"2"`.

Comment: @Guffa: *The expression (b = x) returns neither b nor x, but the value of x* -> I think it returns a **reference** to `x` (and creates a global variable)

Comment: @KooiInc: No, it returns the value of `x`, which is a reference to the array. (It does create a global variable if `b` is not declared already.)

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf, page 85, Simple assignment (=).

Answer (score 0):

See below

`b=x` assigning the data of `x` to `b` and hence you are getting alert as `1,2,3,4,5,6`

`c=(b=x)[2]` is displaying the second content of array i.e. 3.

Below is how `c=(b=x)[2]` works

`c=(b=x)[2]`

`b=x`

`c=b[2]`

let me know if you need further details...

Comment: @user1175687 : See what you get if you write `c=(b=x[1])[2];`. You will understand how is it working...

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of an assigment operator returns value in java script.

Think about it like this:
You make an assignment:

b = x;

Now in object oriented terms, its like invoking a method = on b with an x as an argument

b.=(x)

Here the '=' is like a method name

Now if its the method, why it can't return a value (its return type is other than void)?

Here you can find some additional explanation about this:

[Link1](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047541/why-does-the-assignment-operator-return-a-value-and-not-a-reference)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
c=(b = x)[2]; // b = x; -> shallow copy of the array
              // b      -> now hods the array of x
              // b[2]   -> get the second element of the array
alert(b );    // b is pointing to the array

alert(c );    // c has the 3-rd element (array counting is from 0 - 0,1,2)

b.push("7");  // we add a new item to the array
alert(b);     // 1,2,3,4,5,6
alert(x);     //1,2,3,4,5,6,7 !
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code can be written as:

```
var x = b = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"], c = b[2];
console.log(b); //=> 1,2,3,4,5,6
console.log(c); //=> 3
```

Or even:

```
var c = (x = b = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"])[2];
console.log(b); //=> 1,2,3,4,5,6
console.log(c); //=> 3
```

In `var c = (b=x)[2]`, the parentheses force `b=x` to execute first. In both cases anyhow, when for example used within a function scope, the statement would create variable `b` in the global scope, so I would consider it bad practice.